# How do I get a Data with a return parameter with c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sqldataadapter

I all I have this common method which I used mainly for inserting and getting data from the database. But now I came across a issue that when There's an output value I need to create a new method which accepts and output the values return by the output variable in the query of my db. I have heard that you can use it like this.

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@new_id", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

But how do I change this code as a common method.

Here's my common method code.

```
public DataTable GetDataWithParam(string spName, Dictionary<string, string> parms)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = spName;
                foreach (var para in parms)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(para.Key, para.Value);
                }

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    OpenConnection();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    CloseConnection();
                    return ds.Tables[0];


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

How do I modify the above code to get the output variable? help is greatly appreciated. Also in the db query the return value is an int.

Comment: by using 'ParameterDirection.Output' you can get the inserted row ID(if you have specified the row ID, lets say as primary key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few weeks passed since I asked this question I thought I'll answer this since I got help from my colleagues to find the best solution. You probably want to make a new common generic method like the one in the question but have the output the result by `ParameterDirection`. So here's my answer.

```
public int ExecuteNonQueryWithOutputParamInt(string spName, Dictionary<string, string> parms, Dictionary<string, object> oParam = null)
        {
            string key = null;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = spName;

                foreach (var para in parms)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(para.Key, para.Value);
                }


                if (oParam != null)
                {

                    foreach (var p in oParam)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.Key, p.Value).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        key = p.Key;
                    }
                }
                    this.OpenConnection();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    int returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters[key].Value);
                    this.CloseConnection();
                    return returnValue;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Hope this one help others. Thanks for this assist.

Comment: For what `SqlDataAdapter`? You have it created, but not used in the code.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thanks for pointing out. No need of  `SqlDataAdaptor` since we are using `ExecuteNonQuery()`